# pdfparser - document structure metadata

Tags: pdfbox

I would appreciate a quick pointer on finding out the structural information inside a PDF file - something like the H1, H2, H3 in Microsoft Word. I have been catching up on the stream-oriented PDF file format and am not familiar with the heading operator. Or whether there is such a concept of a heading. I plan to use these heading features to break the PDF down for indexing and searching. That way, I can break down the PDF file into multiple sections for searching.

I found the following in log file. I am guessing this is the beginning of a page but not sure about the significance of them.

> 2018-11-24 16:43:05 DEBUG PDFStreamEngine:260 - processing substream token: PDFOperator{BT}
>   2018-11-24 16:43:15 DEBUG PDFStreamEngine:260 - processing substream token: COSName{GS0}
>   2018-11-24 16:43:21 DEBUG PDFStreamEngine:260 - processing substream token: PDFOperator{gs}
>   2018-11-24 16:43:27 DEBUG PDFStreamEngine:260 - processing substream token: COSName{TT0}
>   2018-11-24 16:43:38 DEBUG PDFStreamEngine:260 - processing substream token: COSInt{1}
>   2018-11-24 16:43:41 DEBUG PDFStreamEngine:260 - processing substream token: PDFOperator{Tf}
>   2018-11-24 16:43:42 DEBUG PDFStreamEngine:260 - processing substream token: COSFloat{0.0031}
>   2018-11-24 16:43:42 DEBUG PDFStreamEngine:260 - processing substream token: PDFOperator{Tc}
>   2018-11-24 16:43:43 DEBUG PDFStreamEngine:260 - processing substream token: COSFloat{-0.0038}
>   2018-11-24 16:43:43 DEBUG PDFStreamEngine:260 - processing substream token: PDFOperator{Tw}
>   2018-11-24 16:43:44 DEBUG PDFStreamEngine:260 - processing substream token: COSFloat{9.96}
>   2018-11-24 16:43:44 DEBUG PDFStreamEngine:260 - processing substream token: COSInt{0}

Comment: Generic pdfs don't have the explicit *structural information* you are looking for. Tagged pdfs can have them.

Comment: Thanks so much for pointing out this is a generic pdf. I think the next step is then to look for patterns in the contents. Would you please guide me where to look for some documents about specifics of these operators and commands? It seems BT means page start. Google search of PostScript and these names has not provided me something useful yet. I found some test code and they point out TT0 being the true type font.

Comment: No BT is BeginText. To see the structure informations you should start with the document catalog… open your PDF with PDFDebugger, then switch to "show internal structure", then go to `Root/StructTreeRoot`. This topic is explained in the PDF specification, see https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf . The content stream does play a role too (but not BT... ET, this is in all files with real text), but it would be better to start with the structure tree IMHO.

Comment: And the method to get the structure tree is `document.getDocumentCatalog().getStructureTreeRoot()`. Btw nobody of the core PDFBox team is an expert in this topic LOL.

Comment: As @Tilman indicated you should look at the pdf specification. He gave a link to the old version which should suffice still. But you mentioned you have a generic pdf, not a tagged one. Thus, chances are there is no **StructTreeRoot**. In that case you indeed have to analyze what happens in the content stream. Pdfbox helps you in this analysis using a class hierarchy of parsers including the `PdfTextStripper` on which you can base your checks. But don't think the tank is easy.

Comment: In the PDF specification look for the appendix A "Operator summary". That is a good start when using PDFDebugger to look at the page content stream. For a general introduction to PDF, see this NSA document: https://theintercept.com/snowden-sidtoday/3676152-ask-raul-pdf-files/ and this Adobe document: https://www.adobe.com/technology/pdfs/presentations/KingPDFTutorial.pdf For how to use the stripper, see the examples in the source code download.

Comment: Thank you again for spending time on this Tilman! I did look into that section and gained some knowledge. It appears to me when the TJ operator is used, there is an array of strings involved and each of the strings looks like either partial letters or fragments of the text then followed by a number. Further reading tells me the numbers are the positions or coordinates of the partial texts after computing the width using the current font. This makes sense. But how does PDF decide how to break up the texts? It looks random to me or there are some specific rules about the underlying font.

Comment: Thanks much mkl for your advice. There is nothing spells "easy" in this as I can witness too :) Reading this gets me thinking of the actual rendering, which is awesome!

Comment: This "breaking up" is done not by PDF but by the creator of the PDF. Likely this is kerning, i.e. taking care that glyphs nicely fit near each other, e.g. in "WA" the "A" should go slightly to the left to get some cover under the "W". Btw this is not required, one can create a PDF without using kerning. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerning It is only important because it shows that you can't trust a word to be in one piece. (But the stripper puts it all back together)